# Plotly Express: How can I adjust the size of marginal distribution plots?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have several datasets I am plotting with plotly express's scatterplot. I am using the option of the marginal distribution plots to show a histogram of the datasets but the problem is that the histograms on the margins tend to be way too big, eclipsing the actual data. An example:[image]

In these plots it's important to see the individual points so I would like to scale the histograms down, but I don't find any documentation on how to adjust the size of the marginal distribution plots separately.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code has not been posted, I will answer assuming that you have enabled marginal in plotly.express. express has a fixed size for individual graphs, I assume, so you can check the graph configuration information (fig.layout) for each graph size (domain ) in the graph configuration information (fig.layout) and set a new value. The answer code is taken from the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/marginal-plots/#scatter-plot-marginals).

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df,
                 x="sepal_length",
                 y="sepal_width",
                 marginal_x="histogram",
                 marginal_y="rug")

# x1=0.8358,x2=0.8408
x1_, x2_ = 0.9, 0.905
# y1=0.7326, y2=0.7426
y1_, y2_ = 0.8, 0.81
fig.layout.xaxis.domain = (0.0, x1_)
fig.layout.xaxis2.domain = (x2_, 1.0)
fig.layout.xaxis3.domain = (0.0, x1_)
fig.layout.xaxis4.domain = (x2_, 1.0)
fig.layout.yaxis.domain = (0.0, y1_)
fig.layout.yaxis2.domain = (0.0, y1_)
fig.layout.yaxis3.domain = (y2_, 1.0)
fig.layout.yaxis4.domain = (y2_, 1.0)

fig.show()
```

[image]

**Graph before customization**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I used exactly the code you have there to create the plot (except for using 'histogram' twice instead of 'histogram' and 'rug'). One thing I don't quite understand is why you have xaxis2, xaxis3, xaxis4 (and same for y). Why is it 4 different settings for each axis instead of two? Could you please explain that and what the choices of x1_, x2_, y1_ and y2_ mean?

Comment: This graph consists of four graphs, with the upper right graph showing all settings disabled. So there are four axes, each with a y-axis and an x-axis.

Comment: Also, the entire axis is divided by the respective ratio of 1. Since new values are needed, we update the values that determine the ratios.

Comment: You can check the layout information of the graph with `print(fig.layout)`.